# Binding transformers to calculated expressions

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to apply #formatNumber binding expression on one of my widgets binding, which is:

```
    @datasource.item.quantity * @datasource.item.price
```

I have tried to apply some usage like:

```
    (@datasource.item.quantity * @datasource.item.price)#formatNumber

     [@datasource.item.quantity * @datasource.item.price]#formatNumber
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: If your expressions are complex then instead of Binding expression, bind a Javascript function. Perform your calculations in the function and return a value from function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The travel approval template from Google should give you what you need. As you can see in the template, it uses a client script in the binding expression to format dates on the dashboard into ISO format.